# Rails - Write comment as a guest with devise. Design proposition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

I want to be able to write a comment as a guest or as a registered user with devise.

My comment model contains **:title**, **:content**, **:user_id**, **:guest_email**, **:guest_website** and **:write_as_guest** as a  boolean.

I wanted to validate the presence of **:guest_email** only when no user is signed_in. But I think I'm not going in the good direction.

I'm managing the form with AJAX/jQuery and I wanted to have a guest form where :content and :guest_email are necessary fields. In another hand, I want to have the user form where only the :content is necessary.

Here is how I tried to go for it.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :set_write_as_guest

  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :content
  validates_presence_of :guest_email, :if => :write_as_guest?

  private

  def write_as_guest?
    self.write_as_guest
  end

  def set_write_as_guest
    if user_signed_in?
      self.write_as_guest = false
    else
      self.write_as_guest = true
    end
  end

end
```

It seems that user_signed_in? method needs before_filter :authenticate_user! then I have the following in my comments_controller

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :create
```

But however I don't want to authenticate to create because that's a guest...

So if somebody would be able to propose me a way to write as a guest or as a user, that would be really appreciated.

Thx

Comment: Doesn't the user association (or absence thereof) imply a guest?  Perhaps do: def write_as_guest? return user_id==0 end

Comment: here you go: [How To: Create a Guest User](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user)

Comment: Thx I used your link to create and sign in a guest user temporarily. I set a user field :role to "guest" and the comment field :write_as_user" to "true" to help me with the validation when a comment is written by a guest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a custom validation like this

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :guest_commentator

    def guest_commentator
      user = User.find(user_id)
      self.errors.add(:user_id => "some error message here ") unless user.nil? 
    end
  end
```